# Android studio не вносит мои изменения, что за чудеса?

Tags: java, android

Итак, перестал реагировать на изменение кода, делаю правки и запускаю приложение на телефоне через режим отладки....
И вижу, что работает старая версия, еще до внесения правок. 
Что случилось? Почему никак не реагирует на изменение кода а отрабатывает старый код написанный еще три дня назад?!
Все нормально работало 2 недели, щас начались чудеса.
При отладке, ставлю брэйки, но они отмечаются крестиками - типа не существует строчки кода этого... http://prntscr.com/c3oi0z

Comment: если ошибок в коде нету, то возможно у вас  Instant run включен,  проверьте в настройках. Ну и пересобрать проект.

Comment: Оо можно подробнее что за инстант ран? 
Где смотреть? ctrl+F9 нажимал пересобирал уже 
Потом просто нажимаю зеленую стрелку как обычно или жука. кароч делаю все как раньше...

Comment: http://prntscr.com/c3p33x - вот пример дебага и игнорирование нового кода

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте отключить Instant Run.

Как это сделать:

Открываем: File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run

и отменяем выбор Enable Instant Run to hot swap...

Comment: Круто, Спасибо!!! Блин заработало!!
КАк так!?! что значит этот пункт и почему перестало работать я настройки не менял точно)